# OpenCV install directory only has one .so file?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, opencv, lambda, zappa

I installed Opencv in a Docker container so that I can upload the linux binaries for support a git project that isn't mine. I need it to run python 3.6 and opencv 3.x, which all seems to be working fine. However, the directory containing the `cv2` folder only has one .so file: `cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` . The project I'm trying to contribute to has the build for opencv py2.7, and that folder has dozens of .so files for many relevant opencv packages, so I feel like something is wrong. Can anyone help?

[image: Here's my output in Docker and inside of relevant folders]

And here's the link to the project I am trying to add support to. 
https://github.com/Miserlou/lambda-packages/tree/master/lambda_packages/OpenCV
Assuming you don't want to unpack the tar, here's how the inside looks for the python 2.7 package [image: here's how the inside looks for the python 2.7 packages]

Comment: How big is `cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`? Note that it's possible to build it self contained.

Comment: @DanMašek It's 24,181 Kb. Some of the individual .so files in 2.7 are as big as that

Comment: Yeah, so that's a all-in-one variant, otherwise it would have been a lot smaller.

Comment: Okay that's good thanks, I'll try sending a pull request and see if it works. Why is `libopencv_imgproc.so.3.1` bigger than that on its own though?

Comment: Thanks though, seems like it was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong as long as you can import it in python and utilize it's functionality. I'm using ROS Kinetic for my research, which comes with a built in release of opencv. It also has just one **cv2.so** file and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: Looks like it was right on its own. Thanks for answering.